# Navigation bar and AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, avcapturesession

I have a `View controller` with `AVCaptureSession` to scan barcode. I picked code [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-scan-a-barcode). I added navigation bar to it. But time, battery life, etc. didn't show.

[image]

[image]

I tried with UINavigation controller and NavigationBar widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely not showing the `UIStatusBar`, try adding this to your ViewController:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .Default
}
```

Another option is setting values for status bar attributes in your main property list file:

[image: UIStatusBar attributes in .plist]

`Status bar style` defines the style of your status bar, see `UIStatusBarStyle` for what option you have.

`View controller-based status bar appearance` defines whether you want to have different styles for each view controller or one style for all view controllers.